# Date format not working in query but working in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

can I please get some help in working this out? I want to change the date format yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy. The DATE_FORMAT works in PHPMyAmin but not when I put in my search query. I'm not very experienced with PHP and despite my research, I can't work out why it won't work - it must be some silly thing I can't see but I have tried it in different positions even and it just does not show up on my HTML table (all other items are OK). In PHPMyAdmin there are no errors, the date shows as dd/mm/yyyy. Thank you so much in advance for whatever you can help me with.
This is the code in PHPMyAdmin:

```
`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Fixture_Date,'%d/%m/%Y'), f.WeeKNo, f.HomeTeam, f.AwayTeam, s.HT_score, s.AT_score FROM Fixtures f LEFT JOIN Scores s ON f.FixtureID=s.FixtureID`
```

And this is my PHP query

```
<?php 

$keyword=trim ($_POST['keyword']);
$query=$conn->prepare ( "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Fixture_Date,'%d/%m/%Y'), f.WeeKNo, f.HomeTeam, f.AwayTeam, s.HT_score, s.AT_score FROM Fixtures f LEFT JOIN Scores s ON f.FixtureID=s.FixtureID WHERE f.Fixture_Date LIKE '$keyword' or WeekNo LIKE '$keyword' 
    or HomeTeam LIKE '$keyword' or AwayTeam LIKE '$keyword'");
    
    $query->execute();
    
    while ($row=$query->fetch()){ ?>
    <tr>
                     
        <td><?php echo $row['Fixture_Date'];?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row['WeekNo'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['HomeTeam'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['HT_score'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['AwayTeam'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['AT_score'];?></td>
    </tr>
    
    <?php
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($row);` inside the loop, that will show you what the _problem_ is. Then go read up on what a (column) _Alias_ in SQL is.

Comment: *I want to change the date format yyyy/mm/dd* Does the date with this format is stored in VARCHAR column? If so then convert it to date using STR_TO_DATE() then apply DATE_FORMAT().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the results in PHPMyAdmin, you'll see the column name is now `DATE_FORMAT(Fixture_Date,'%d/%m/%Y')`. You need to alias the column so you can pull it back out easier:

```
$query=$conn->prepare ( "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Fixture_Date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS Fixture_Date, f.WeeKNo, f.HomeTeam, f.AwayTeam, s.HT_score, s.AT_score FROM Fixtures f LEFT JOIN Scores s ON f.FixtureID=s.FixtureID WHERE f.Fixture_Date LIKE '$keyword' or WeekNo LIKE '$keyword' 
or HomeTeam LIKE '$keyword' or AwayTeam LIKE '$keyword'");
```

By the way, since you're using prepare statements, you really should be binding your variables as well. You can find the instructions for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and
[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: thank you for your help. That sort of worked because something strange happened,  although the date now looks as I wanted it, the WeekNo has disappeared from the table. Is this because I'm not binding the variables? And just on that, when I read the PDO info, since I'm fetching an array, does this means that I should be using "foreach" instead of the "while" loop?

Comment: No, you want the while loop, so that it will iterate the loop while retrieving the results. The WeekNo should still be there. Try `var_dump($row);` inside of your loop to see what keys and data are in the row.

Comment: Beat me to giving this answer.  @Nessy: Using an alias on one field should not have any effect on other fields, as long as the aliases aren't conflicting.

Comment: I can see the WeekNo there. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is part of the dump: array(12) { ["Fixture_Date"]=> string(10) "09/07/2019" [0]=> string(10) "09/07/2019" ["WeeKNo"]=> string(6) "Week 1" [1]=> string(6) "Week 1"

Comment: `WeeKNo` is what's showing, and you're probably trying to get `WeekNo`. Capitalization makes a huge difference in PHP

Comment: @anyber, I feel so silly, that was the issue!!!  The table is now showing as it should. Sorry, it's 1:30 am and I'm ready to drop. Without your help,  there wouldn't be much sleep either so TRIPLE THANK YOU!

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, thank you, I will watch out for that too! :)